# How to make my stick rotating after bouncing with button long pressed?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

Basically I want to make bouncing stick and rotate control, with the left-right button.i'm facing an issue that the rotate not good as I expected because it won't follow my button like being affected by something after bouncing,

[image]

I'm using 2d physics material with `friction = 1` and `Bounciness = 0.9797` for perfect bouncing also attached to rigidbody2d.

I don't know, should I attach it on collider?

here my Player control Script:

```cs
public Rigidbody2D r2d;

public float vertical;
public float horizontal;
public Joystick joystick;

private void Start() {
    r2d = gameObject.GetComponent < Rigidbody2D > ();
    joystick = FindObjectOfType < Joystick > ();
}

private void Update() {
    Movement();
}

public void Movement() {
    r2d.velocity = r2d.velocity.normalized * 7f;

    //horizontal = joystick.Horizontal;
    //vertical = joystick.Vertical;

    //if (horizontal == 0 && vertical == 0)
    //{
    //    Vector3 curRot = transform.localEulerAngles;
    //    Vector3 homeRot = transform.localEulerAngles;

    //    transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.Slerp(curRot, homeRot, Time.deltaTime * 2);
    //}
    //else
    //{
    //    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, 0f, Mathf.Atan2(horizontal, vertical) * -180 / Mathf.PI);
    //}
}

public Vector3 target;
public float rotationSpeed = 10f;
public float offset = 5;

public void turnLeft() {
    Vector3 dir = target - transform.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle + offset));
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, -rotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}

public void turnRight() {
    Vector3 dir = target - transform.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle + offset));
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever there is a `Rigidbody`/`Rigidbody2D` involved you do **not** want to manipulate anything via the `.transform` component!

This breaks the physics, collision detection and leads to strange movements basically the transform "fighting" against physics for priority.

What you rather want to do would be e.g. adjusting the [`Rigidbody2D.angularVelocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-angularVelocity.html)

```
public void turnLeft()
{
    // Note that Time.deltaTime only makes sense if this is actually called every frame!
    r2d.angularVelocity -= rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}

public void turnRight()
{
    r2d.angularVelocity += rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: It seems work for me without `time.deltaTime`  even though I put it on the update, This answer really helps me out.